# Linux raid suddenly not assembling when rebooting

Tags: fedora, raid, mdadm

I had a very simple RAID0 set up with just two disks, and it was assembling fine for a long time after rebooting.

Then suddenly it is not loading anymore.

**mdadm.conf:**

```
DEVICE partitions

ARRAY /dev/md0 level=raid0 num-devices=2 metadata=1.2 name=simernes:0 UUID=xxxxxxxx:xx1337xx:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx devices=/dev/sda,/dev/sdc
```

What could be the reason for this happening, and how should I start troubleshooting?

I've seen in some old posts people referencing a mdadm service, but there is no such service found on my computer (Fedora 31).

```
$ sudo systemctl status mdadm
Unit mdadm.service could not be found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you did not create a partition table before creating the RAID. I have the same issue in one of the server with same setup. You can try reassemble the RAID by using "assume clean". I do it every time when the server reboot.

```
sudo mdadm --create --assume-clean --level=0 --raid-devices=2 /dev/md0 /dev/sda /dev/sdc --run
```

If you wish to read more before doing this, refer to [RAID Recovery](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_Recovery)

Comment: On a sidenote, do you think it's a good idea to reference the disks with /dev/sd* or should I preferably use some sort of UID?

Comment: This is a good question. AFAIK The mdam recognizes the disks by reading the superblock from each disk, so it is safe to create a RAID array with /dev/sd*, and reassemble it in the same way if nothing changed in the server. In the event that the identifier has changed, you most likely couldn't assemble the RAID since the superblock is missing (I used 'most likely' because I never test it, but in theory it should work that way). By then you will need to run mdadm --detail --scan to scan and identify the RAID members.

Comment: This seems to have worked at least in restoring the raid, but there are no files on the raid now anymore. I expected something like this to happen, so I didn't have any important data on the raid. Are you saying that I should have created a partition table first before creating the raid?

Comment: Have you tried putting in the metadata=1.2 and try again? Also, just make sure you put in the right device. I can see u skipped sdb, and only use sda and sdc. Hope that is intended and not a typo. Yes, always create a partition table first before configure a RAID.

Comment: So the files actually started showing up after a while, even without the `metadata=1.2`. If you have some information available on the subject, could you direct me to how I should go about creating a partition table in this manner?

Comment: @simernes I'm glad that you got your files back. Thanks for confirming the metadata is not needed. To create partition table, you can use either fdisk, gnome-disks (GUI) or gparted (GUI) to accomplish the task. I usually use fdisk for new hdd, it is simple and easy. It will be redundant for me to write it here, so pls follow instructions in this link: https://www.howtogeek.com/106873/how-to-use-fdisk-to-manage-partitions-on-linux/